# CSS '+' in right bottom corner of element

Tags: html, css

How can I do something like this:
[image: Example]

It  will be on `:hover` and `:active` states.

Comment: Can you post the code which you tried ?

Comment: Please provide us with some code, so we can help you. Even better a fiddle or something like that

Answer (score 1):

Here is some code to get started.

```css
ul{
  list-style: none;
  background-color: coral;
}
li {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
li:hover:after{
  content: "+";
  position: absolute;
  right: 2px;
  bottom: 2px;
  color: blue;
  position: absolute;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>About Us</li>
    <li>Mission</li>
    <li>Vision</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**Note:** Try to implement the requirement and then ask for help when necessary.

Comment: @PraveenKumar : Thanks machi!